# Union of plotted regions as sum of colors

Tags: plotting, color, regions

I wish to plot 2 functions $f$ and $g$ so that the region bounded by $f$ has color $c_f$, the region bounded by $g$ has color $c_g$, and the region bounded by both has color $c_f+c_g$.
E.g. $c_f$ is red, $c_g$ is blue, $c_f+c_g$ is magenta.

I tried this:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -π, +π}, Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, Blue}, 2 -> {Axis, Red}}]
```

[image: bad]

I found no documentation on how to do additive mixture of colors in a plot. How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach would be to plot a third function which defines the overlap region.

```
overlap[f_List] := Piecewise[{{Sign[First@f] Min[Abs@f], Equal @@ Sign[f]}}, I]

Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], overlap[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}]}, {x, -π, π},
 Filling -> {1 -> {0, Blue}, 2 -> {0, Red}, 3 -> {0, Thread[Red + Blue, RGBColor]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's a slight kludge, but it works. I actually defined overlap thus:
`overlap[x_, y_] := UnitStep[Sign[x] Sign[y]] Sign[x] Min[Abs[x], Abs[y]]`

Comment: @strake: For two functions the easiest thing to do might be `Median[{x, y, 0}]`.

Comment: @RahulNarain, that's clever.

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks, that's much neater.

Answer (score 4):

One easy way will be to use `Opacity`!

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -\[Pi], +\[Pi]},
Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, Directive[Opacity[.7], Blue]},
2 -> {Axis, Directive[Opacity[.7], Red]}}]
```

[image]

**Update:**
Here comes a better solution for your problem. The function is pretty much self explanatory as far as the argument names are concerned. Given a list of functions to be plotted together we take any one of them and use `Plot` to sample this function. Then we do a condition check on the sample to find the x-coordinates for the common region. We do a `ListLinePlot` for this common region and use `Show` to display it on the default plot.

```
UnionPlot[funs_, samplingFunction_, {start_, end_}, fillingUnion_, 
  plot_, plotPoints_: 600, maxRecursion_: 4] := 
 Block[{union, sample, fun},
  union = 
   If[And @@ (#[x] <= 0 & /@ ##), Evaluate@(Max @@ (#[x] & /@ ##)), 
      If[And @@ (#[x] > 0 & /@ ##), Evaluate@(Min @@ (#[x] & /@ ##)), 
       0]] &@funs;
  sample = (First@Cases[Plot[Evaluate[funs[[samplingFunction]][x]],
  {x, start, end},PlotPoints -> plotPoints, MaxRecursion -> maxRecursion], 
       Line[a___] :> a, Infinity])[[All, 1]]; 
  fun = Function[x, Evaluate@union];
  Show[plot, 
   ListLinePlot[Transpose@{sample, fun[#] & /@ sample}, 
    Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
    Evaluate@fillingUnion, Axes -> False]]
  ]
```

**Usage:**

Lets take a list of functions to be plotted and define a `FillingStyle` for the common region!

```
funs = {Sin[3 #] &, Cos[4 #] &, .8 Sin[2 #]^2 Cos[3 #] &};
commonfillingStyle = FillingStyle -> Blend[{Red, Blue, Green}, .3];
```

Now we will use the 3rd function to sample the x-coordinate of our plot.

```
UnionPlot[funs, 3, {-Pi, Pi}, commonfillingStyle, 
 Plot[Evaluate[#[x] & /@ funs], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, None}, 2 -> {Axis, Red},3 -> {Axis, Orange}}]]
```

[image]

Your example case with `commonfillingStyle = FillingStyle -> Blend[{Red, Blue}, .5]` becomes the following.

[image]

Comment: Not additive mixture; try swapping the colors. I tried this with my actual functions and it was unreadable.

Comment: @strake Check the update! Tell me if this solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not quite sure how to use this in [my case](http://strake.me.uk/_docs/visibility.nb). I tried to rewrite the plotted expression as a function evaluation but failed.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Region` Functionality:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
funcs = {Sin[x + π/4], Cos[x]};
overlap = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   y > 0 && y <= funcs[[1]] && y < funcs[[2]] || 
    y < 0 && y >= funcs[[1]] && y >= funcs[[2]], {{x, -π, π}, 
    y}];

p1 = Plot[funcs, {x, -π, π}
   , PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}
   , Filling -> {
     {1 -> {Axis, Directive[Blue, HatchFilling[1, 3, 6]]}}
     , {2 -> {Axis, Directive[Red, HatchFilling[2, 3, 6]]}}}
   , PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
   ];

p2 = RegionPlot[overlap
   , PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1, Lighter@Lighter@Purple]]
   , BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Purple, Thick]
   , PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"
   ];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: `p1` would be able to show the overlapping regions for display purposes only. Regions can also be used to do calculations.